# cellForRowAtIndexPath and numberOfRowsInSection conflicting in tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase

I am creating an app that is retrieving data from Firebase. In my 'MealViewController' I have a TableView that has the view controller as it's delegate and data source. I am getting the issue "Type 'MealViewController" does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource' because it requires both :numberOfRowsInSection: and :cellForRowAtIndexPath: . However, when I add both, another issue appears - 'Definition conflict with previous value'. I've looked through all the Stack Overflow issues related to this, and no luck has been had. Here's my View Controller:

```
    class MealViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var bgImage: UIImageView?
    var image : UIImage = UIImage(named: "pizza")!
    @IBOutlet weak var blurEffect: UIVisualEffectView!
    @IBOutlet weak var mealTableView: UITableView!
    var items = [MealItem]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


        bgImage = UIImageView(image: image)
        bgImage?.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
        bgImage!.frame = view.layer.bounds

        self.view.addSubview(bgImage!)
        //self.bgImage?.addSubview(blurEffect)
        //bgImage!.bringSubviewToFront(blurEffect)
        view.bringSubviewToFront(blurEffect)

        mealTableView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        mealTableView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        mealTableView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5


        let ref = Firebase(url: "https://order-template.firebaseio.com/grocery-items")

        mealTableView.delegate = self
        mealTableView.dataSource = self


        // MARK: UIViewController Lifecycle

        func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

            return 1
        }

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            print(items.count)
            return items.count

        }

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> MealsCellTableViewCell { //issue occurs here

            let groceryItem = items[indexPath.row]

            if let cell = mealTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ItemCell") as? MealsCellTableViewCell {


                cell.configureCell(groceryItem)

                // Determine whether the cell is checked

                self.mealTableView.reloadData()

                return cell

            }
        }

        func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
            super.viewDidAppear(animated)

            // [1] Call the queryOrderedByChild function to return a reference that queries by the "completed" property
            ref.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

                var newItems = [MealItem]()

                for item in snapshot.children {

                    let mealItem = MealItem(snapshot: item as! FDataSnapshot)
                    newItems.append(mealItem)
                }

                self.items = newItems
                self.mealTableView.reloadData()
            })

        }



        func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
            super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

        }

        func willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation(toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: NSTimeInterval) {



        }



    }

    override func willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation(toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: NSTimeInterval) {

        bgImage = UIImageView(image: image)
        bgImage?.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill

        bgImage!.frame = view.layer.bounds
        self.view.addSubview(bgImage!)
        view.bringSubviewToFront(blurEffect)

    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


        // MARK: UITableView Delegate methods






}
```

Comment: Please show on what line this error appears. Maybe it's unrelated to table view at all.

Comment: The first issue is at the class statement, the second one I edited and marked, which is at the cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Oh, just noticed your dataSource methods are actually nested :) Thus your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is just a local function, which is invisible outside of `viewDidLoad`. You should move all your nested functions out of `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Also, don't call `reloadData` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: Change any references to mealTableView to self.mealTableView and you can leave those references where they are. When you are referring to class level variables, reference them with self, it also makes it more readable.

Comment: Also let groceryItem = items[indexPath.row] should be self.items. Please be careful with how variables are referenced as it can be confusing when you have variables at a function level vs class level. Class level, use self. and function or local use the straight variable name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cellForRowAtIndexPath should look like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellIdentifier = "ItemCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MealsCellTableViewCell

    let groceryItem = self.items[indexPath.row]

    cell.configureCell(groceryItem)

    return cell
}
```

Note that the returned cell is a MealsCellTableViewCell which is a subclass of UITableViewCell so it conforms to that class.

Don't change the function definition as that will make it not conform to what the delegate protocol specifies.

Here's a link to the Apple documentation for the specific implementation of custom tableView cells for reference.

[Create a Table View](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson7.html)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your view controller's conformance to UITableViewDatasource `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method is not right. You should refactor your implementation of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method like so:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let groceryItem = items[indexPath.row]

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ItemCell") as? MealsCellTableViewCell else {
        fatalError("No cell with identifier: ItemCell")
    }

    cell.configureCell(groceryItem)

    return cell
}
```

You also need to move the datasource methods out of `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: If mealTableView delegate is moved out of the viewDidLoad() than the issue 'Expected declaration appears'. After changing the implementation there is still the issue of not conforming to the protocol dataSource, and a new issue of "cannot convert return expression of type 'MealsCellTableViewCell' to return type 'UITableView'"

Answer (score 0):

You return `MealsCellTableViewCell` instead of `UITableViewCell` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, that's the reason.

Comment: both the issue of 'Definition conflicts with previous value' and the nonconformance with the class are still present

Comment: @JohnHarding As long as MealsCellTableViewCell is a UITableViewCell then it's fine to return it from the method as it is a type of UITableViewCell - this is common practice. However, your function definition should return UITableViewCell (so it conforms) instead of  MealsCellTableViewCell